# How to check whether an SSD will fit into my HP notebook?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I want to buy an SSD to replace the broken traditional HDD in my HP TM2T-1000.

However, some people online say that the physical size of the HP hard drive is a little smaller at the corner than other regular hard drive.

How I can check whether a hard drive is going to fit my notebook?

Comment: How do you know the drive is bad? It could be the motherboard, connectors, etc.

Comment: I heard some noise from the computer. However, I am not an expert. Would anyone please give me some suggestion of how to check whether it is the drive problem?

Comment: Noise could be fans as well, or a disc drive... Fans may make sense to cause overheating. What happens on boot? Exact messages or text could help.

Comment: == No bootable device-- insert boot disk and press any key ==

Comment: Please ask a separate question about the actual boot problems and diagnosing the original drive. The question here is how to find out whether an SSD will fit or not. Having two (partly unrelated) questions mixed in one will be confusing to visitors who might end up with same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crucial.com has a fantastic resource for checking memory and SSD compatibility.

The [result for your laptop](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=TouchSmart%20tm2t%20Series) states that [this 128GB drive](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=C69E85A1A5CA7304) is compatible as well as several other lower density drives.

Comment: I love your answer. I did a search myself a few hours ago. There were some sites that guarantee their hard drive match my notebook, but the lowest price is $120 and the size is small too. Crucial.com has 64GB for $64. The price is much better. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. My personal recommendation is that you go with the 128GB, since even that does not go very far these days. You can always buy an external hard drive for backup storage (around $80/TB), but keep in mind that it can be annoying to try to manage, say, an iTunes library with an external drive as storage.